Azure WebJobs on linux plan suddenly stop and disappear from portal UI
We have a continuous WebJob running without any problems for a week.
Suddenly, it stops working. The only information available in the logs is:
[09/06/2024 08:37:39 > 28045c: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[09/06/2024 17:50:29 > 28045c: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 143
[09/06/2024 17:50:29 > 28045c: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds
[09/06/2024 17:50:29 > 28045c: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
[09/06/2024 17:50:29 > 28045c: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton lock is released
[09/06/2024 17:50:29 > 28045c: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton lock is acquired
--for 2 days continuous web job is not running, triggered jobs is not scheduled --
[09/08/2024 18:44:21 > 28045c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[09/08/2024 18:44:21 > 28045c: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is True

The WebJob is not restarted, and all WebJobs (1 continuous, 1 triggered) disappear from the WebJobs blade in the portal UI.
Strangely, navigating to the App Service/'Log stream' blade in the Azure portal causes the WebJobs to appear and start. No actual restart is needed.
The application has the 'Always On' option enabled.
The web application (default Azure app) has been running without problems the entire time (we added a ping every 15 minutes after the issue first occurred).
Memory usage never exceeds 50% of the plan (B3, 7GB), and only 2 app services are hosted on this app service plan.
This issue has occurred twice in the last 30 days, in 2 different subscriptions and different regions.
I'm unsure what to do next, as we did not encounter these problems with Windows plans using this setting.

Please share your webjob code.

Did you check running it in different systems ?

It's a .net console app+basic run.sh bash script, nothing fancy.
Yes, previously on Windows plan we had no such problems.

Did you check LogStream for more details?

You can enable ApplicationInsights to get more details about the issue.

fyi as written, this is off-topic, as it doesn't appear to be a programming question. If it is programming related, you should edit your question to provide a [mcve] with all relevant details. Right now you've only talked about your service tier and some error about it "stopped working."

Well, I described precisely what is happening.
There are no logs as it looks like Azure kills the WebJob.
The main question is why WebJobs are not restared and disappear from the portal UI.
